# 3 classes (0, 1, 4) on Boost graph cut

Tags: c++, boost

I obtain strange results when I use the BGL boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow() function. I though I would see 2 classes (0-1 or anything else, but only 2!) but I often see three classes: 0, 1 and 4.

For example, using the image below with

- source: middle pixel on left border
- sink: middle pixel on right border
- horizontal edge cost = 10 * e^(rightPixel / 50)
- vertical edge code = 0.1.

[image: 8 bits image]

I obtain the following results:

```
444444444444400000000000000000
444444444444440000000000000000
444444444444440000000000000000
444444444444440000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444000000000000000
444444444444444411000000000000
444444444444444444000000000000
444444444444444444000000000000
444444444444444444000000000000
444444444441111111000000000000
444444444440000000000000000000
444444444440000000000000000000
444444444440000000000000000000
444444444440000000000000000000
444444444444000000000000000000
444444444444000000000000000000
444444444444100000000000000000
444444444444110000000000000000
444444444444110000000000000000
444444444444411000000000000000
444444444444444400000000000000
444444444444444400000000000000
444444444444444400000000000000
444444444444444400000000000000
444444444444444400000000000000
```

Can someone explain the real meaning of these classes? I'm quite sure 4 is the source class and 0 is the sink class, but what about 1? I found nothing in the documentation about that. I think it means a "not sure" horizontal zone, but why would it means that?!?

Second question. Are the 1 reliable? Would it be possible to use them to find a smoother border like in the image below? The goal would be to choose one of the green pixel instead of the red one who are too far to the right. I mean, I know that I could use the 1 in this case to do it, but can I trust them to be there when I need them? :)

[image: Colored border]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whats the output you show (0, 1, 4)? Is this the vertex_color?

Comment: No, it's not color values. The goal of a maxflow/mincut is to divide the graph in two classes, so those number are actual class of each pixel.

It's obtained by one of the out parameters of boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(), as you can see in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178978/boost-grid-graph-and-graph-cut-on-image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example:

```
boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(graph,
     make_iterator_property_map(&capacity[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)), 
     make_iterator_property_map(&residual_capacity[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)),
     make_iterator_property_map(&reverse_edges[0], get(boost::edge_index, graph)), //CHANGED
     make_iterator_property_map(&groups[0], get(boost::vertex_index, graph)),
     get(boost::vertex_index, graph),
     s,
     t
 );
```

They call the following constructor from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp):

```
boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(Graph& g,
                       CapacityEdgeMap cap,
                       ResidualCapacityEdgeMap res_cap,
                       ReverseEdgeMap rev,
                       ColorMap color,
                       IndexMap idx,
                       typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor src,
                       typename graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor sink)
```

Which means, that what you think are classes are indeed the colors. According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.html),

> If the color of a vertex after running the algorithm is black the vertex belongs to the source tree else it belongs to the sink-tree (used for minimum cuts).

Now if you look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/graph/properties.hpp) at the default color map, the colors are an enum going from 0 to 4, where 4 is black.

**With all of this, you can conclude that 4 is indeed the source, but everything else (including the 1's) belong to the sink!**

The different color probably depends on the implementation itself, but I don't think you can make any assumptions about the 1's without knowing what the implementation is...

Comment: Ah dammit. My assupmtion about this parameter was wrong, just because it was named "groups" :) Thanks, this answers my question.